# Creating a single map composed of three separate shapefiles

Tags: r, shapefile, ggmap, tmap

I have the following shapefiles:

```
qmasp <- st_read("Rock_Lobster_(Spiny_Red)_QMAs.shp", quiet = TRUE)
statShp <- st_read("Rock_Lobster_Statistical_Areas.shp", quiet = TRUE)
NE_countries <- st_read("ne_110m_admin_0_countries", quiet = TRUE)
```

I want them to appear together as a single map. Each shapefile looks like this (see images):

[image: Rock_Lobster_(Spiny_Red)_QMAs.shp]
[image: Rock_Lobster_Statistical_Areas.shp]
[image: "ne_110m_admin_0_countries"]

and I am using the following code:

transform QMA shapefile to an sf object

```
qmasf=st_as_sf(qmasp)
qmasf4326=st_transform(qmasf, 4326)
```

then NZ UTM for plotting

```
qmasf2134=st_transform(qmasf, 2193)#2134
qmasf2134 %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf(aes(fill=FishstockC))
```

transform Stat Area Shapefile to sf object

```
statsf=st_as_sf(statShp)
statsf4326=st_transform(statsf, 4326)
```

then NZ UTM for plotting

```
statsf2134=st_transform(statsf, 2134)#check if NZ2000 is better
stats<-statsf2134 %>%
 ggplot()+
  geom_sf(fill= 'White')+
  geom_sf_text(
    aes(label = Statistica),
    size = 4 / .pt
  )
stats
```

Plot Map

```
theme_set(theme_bw())

newzealand <- ne_countries(country="new zealand", type="countries", scale = 'large', returnclass = "sf")

ggplot(data = newzealand) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(crs = 2193)
```

I can then plot data points using coordinate data onto specific polygons from the QMA shapefile on the map with this code:

to prepare data for plotting on map

```
samples_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(d2, coords=c("Longitude","Latitude"), crs=4326)
```

Subset CRA3 polygon from the QMA shapefile

```
CRA3_shapefile<-qmasf2134 %>%
  filter(FishstockC %in% c("CRA2","CRA3"))
CRA3_shapefile
```

which looks like this (see below):

[image: selected polygons]

or this depending on which code I use:
[image: Zoomed in image of selected polygons]

My questions are, (i) How do I produce a map that has all three shape files on the one image, essentially layered on top of one another? (ii) Why is my map of New Zealand so small and how do I make it the same size as the other shapefiles, without losing Chatham Island (the third island of New Zealand)? This island is to the East of the north and south island of New Zealand.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just a follow-up to my answer. The reason the extent of your map is so large is because Avaiki Nui/Cook Islands are an administrative territory of Aotearoa/New Zealand. In your map, Avaiki Nui is too small to show up.

Comment: Hypothetically, could I remove the Cook Islands from the map to enlarge it? And if so, how would I do that in the script? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Thank you so much you're brilliant! I'm just attempting the script now, I will let you know if I have any hiccups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tēnā koe e hoa, here's a repex given we don't have access to your data. You can think of `coord_sf()` as a zoom function. To get the extent of your data, use `st_bbox()` and work forwards from there. With some trial and error, you'll achieve the desired result. The example image uses the xlim/ylim (long/lat) as stated. For each layer, add a new `geom_sf()` as shown below. You have to explicitly state the `data =` each time, but I prefer this approach as I find it easier to follow. The `geom_sf()` are plotted in order, so your background layers go first:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

newzealand <- ne_countries(country = "new zealand", 
                           type = "countries", 
                           scale = 'large', 
                           returnclass = "sf") %>%
  st_transform(2193)

# Dummy CRA3_shapefile
CRA3_shapefile <- data.frame(cra = rep(c("CRA2", "CRA3"), each = 4),
                             lat = c(5700000, 5800000, 5800000, 5700000,
                                     5800000, 5900000, 5900000, 5800000),
                             long = c(2000000, 2000000, 2200000, 2200000)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat")) %>%
  group_by(cra) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  st_set_crs(2193)

# Dummy point data. set.seed() for replicable result, only needed for dummy point data
set.seed(123)
sf_points <- data.frame(lat = sample(5700000:5900000, 20),
                        long = sample(2000000:2200000, 20)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat")) %>%
  st_cast("POINT") %>%
  st_set_crs(2193)

# Get extent of newzealand data as basis for setting coord_sf limits
st_bbox(newzealand)
xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax 
1092701 4165390 3357853 9024853 

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = CRA3_shapefile,
          aes(fill = cra)) +
  geom_sf(data = newzealand,
          colour = "black") +
  geom_sf(data = sf_points,
          colour = "grey40",
          size = 1.5) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(1002701, 2557853),
           ylim = c(4165390, 6204853))
```

[image: result]

***Update based on OP's comment***

Often it is more desirable to filter out the unnecessary geometries rather than using `coord_sf()`. It's trickier in this case as your NZ data are MULTIPOLYGON so every individual polygon will share the same non-geometry values (attributes in ArcGIS parlance). In other words, there's no way of knowing which polygons represent Avaiki Nui/Cook Islands other than by their long/lat values.

In your case, the simplest approach is to 'borrow' the max ylim value from the previous step e.g 6204853 and to filter out everything north of 6204853. This approach involves breaking your MULTIPOLYGON into individual polygons using `st_cast()`:

```
# Convert MULTIPOLYGON TO POLYGON (you can safely ignore the resultant warning)
nz1 <- newzealand %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) # This column added as a key for filtering

# 1. Extract coordinates from nz1
# 2. Filter out polygon ids north of max ylim value
# 3. left_join() polygon ids to nz1
# 4. Filter out unwanted polygons
# NOTE: the Y and L2 columns referenced here are 
#       default names generated by data.frame(st_coordinates(nz1))
nz2 <- data.frame(st_coordinates(nz1)) %>%
  filter(Y <= 6204853) %>%
  select(L2) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  left_join(nz1, ., by = join_by(id == L2), keep = TRUE) %>%
  filter(!is.na(L2))
```